# Create a dependent dropdown for multiple tabs and multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

```html
//CREATE PRIMARY DROPDOWN LIST
function createPrimaryDrpdwon() {
 /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */

   var dataSS           = "Lookup";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
   var dropSS           = "Jun 15";         //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
   var primaryDataRange = "A4:A14";       //Data range for primary dropdown
   var primaryDropRange = "H3:H200";       //Range which primary dropdown set

  var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();

  var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);

  var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();

   primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
}

 
//CREATE SECONDARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onEdit(){
 /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
 var dataSS       = "Lookup";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
 var dropSS       = "Jun 15";         //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
 var allDataRange = "B5:C183";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent)
 var primaryDDCol = 8;               //Column number of the primary drop down

  var dropSS_      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS);
  var dropDData    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange).getValues();

  var activeCell   = dropSS_.getActiveCell();

  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();

  var activeRow    = activeCell.getRow();

  

  if(activeColumn==primaryDDCol){

    var dep_Col         = primaryDDCol+1;

    var dep_Row         = activeRow;

    var depCell         = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);

    var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();

    var validationRule  = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected)).build();

    

    depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);

  }

}

 

function getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected){

  var dependenList = [];

  var j = 0;

  if(dropDData != null){

    for(i=0; i<dropDData.length; i++){

      if(dropDData[i][0]==primarySelected){

        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];

        j++;

      }

    }

  }

  return dependenList;

}
```

I am trying to write a script that will allow for dependent dropdowns on multiple sheets within the workbook. I have already created a script to work on one sheet and it works good but I have to change the name of the sheet for each for instance if each tab was a week of the month "5-4-20", "5-11-20", "5-18-20" etc. but the same information is collected in that week tab how can I run a script for the same dependent drop down to work the same way for every tab?

Comment: Perhaps something  like `if(e.range.getSheet().getName().match(/\d{1,}-\d{1,}-\d{2}/)  && other stuff ....}`

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please focus.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 3):

### Replace the static definition of `var dropSS`

**First possibility: run the script on all sheets apart from `Lookup`**
[`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets) allows you to retrieve all available sheets and run the script on all of them.

Sample:

```
function iterateThroughAllSheets(){
  var dataSS           = "Lookup";             
  var primaryDataRange = "A4:A14";       
  var primaryDropRange = "H3:H200";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var dropSS = sheets[i].getName();
    if (dropSS != dataSS){
      // continue the rest of your code as before
      var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();     
      var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);      
      var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();      
      primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```

**Second possibility: run the script only on the newest sheet**

Assuming that your sheets will always be appended to the right, the newest sheet will have the highest index - corresponding to `sheets.length`.

Sample:

```
function runOntheLastSheet(){
  var dataSS           = "Lookup";             
  var primaryDataRange = "A4:A14";       
  var primaryDropRange = "H3:H200";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber = sheets.length;
  var dropSS = sheets[sheetNumber-1].getName();  
  // continue the rest of your code as before
  var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();     
  var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);      
  var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();      
  primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule); 
}
```

**Third possibility: Run the script on the [active sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet)**

Define `var dropSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()` and run the script when the sheet of your choice is active.

> For all three possibilities, please modify `function onEdit()`
>   accordingly.