# Conditional Data Validation in Google Sheets, limit second drop-down based on first drop-down

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I want to select a category in a drop down, then limit the next drop-down in that row to items only in that category, then lookup the value for that item and display it from a data table. I would prefer to avoid scripting if at all possible. I swear I've done it before, but maybe it was in Excel...

I have a table where first column represents category and second represents item. Categories are non-unique, Items are unique. I want a "selection" sheet where the first column chooses from available Categories in the first column of data and second column chooses from Items that have that category in column 1 in the data table. Pictures to show desired end result, but set manually. How do I make this happen dynamically? In this case, I cannot have a header of "A, B, C" with the items listed below, as each item has it's own value that will be pulled with a lookup in the third column of the selection area.

---

In selection area, first column has "A" selected, so options are only "Z", "X", and "Y" for second drop down.

[image: First column has "A" selected, so options are only "Z", "X", and "Y" for second drop down.]

---

In selection area, first entry now has "B" selected, so options are only "W" and "V" for second drop down.

[image: First entry now has "B" selected, so options are only "W" and "V" for second drop down.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can do it with a combination of [named ranges](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) and [=INDIRECT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Workflow:

- Go on `Data -> Named ranges` and create named ranges in column B corresponding to each different value of column A

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

- In column E, create a data validation with column A as range
- Select a dummy column (e.g. `D`) and paste the formula `=INDIRECT(E1)` - this will display in this column the data belonging to the named range chosen in column `E`

- Create a second validation in column `F` taking column `D` as range
  [image]
- This will result in a dependent dropdown - you can set the auxilliary column `D` to hidden.

---

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. Is there any way to do this dynamically, though? If I add a new entry to the bottom with an existing category, the named range method won't work. Using this method and trying to stay dynamic, would I need a second data set where each category has a list of items in a column, instead of one data set where one column is category, one is item, and one is value? I guess I could then remove the category in the data table. Also, can't you use `=INDIRECT()` in data validation without needing another hidden column?

Comment: For a more dynamic approach I am afraid that you would not get around a simple script.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to either look into scripting or go back to Excel.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652900/11599789).