# Google Sheet - Multiple Dependent Dropdown on different tabs on the Same Worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was able to create 2 scripts that will allow for dependent drop-downs (data validation) on multiple sheets within the same workbook based on this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61644066/create-a-dependent-dropdown-for-multiple-tabs-and-multiple-rows?rq=3). Both dependent dropdowns (data validation) rely on the same tab for their value list (Data Validation) but different ranges.

I am running into the issue of getting both scripts to work, only 1 of the 2 scripts would work at a time. How can I get both scripts to work at the same time?

For dependent drop-down 1 my script is as follows:

```
function dependent_drop_down_1(){
  var dataSS           = "Data Validation";             
  var primaryDataRange = "A2:A10";       
  var primaryDropRange = "B4";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var dropSS = sheets[i].getName();
    if (dropSS != dataSS){
      // continue the rest of your code as before
      var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();     
      var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);      
      var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();      
      primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}


//CREATE SECONDARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onEdit(){
 /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
 var dataSS       = "Data Validation";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
 var dropSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()         //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
 var allDataRange = "A2:B10";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent)
 var primaryDDCol = 2;               //Column number of the primary drop down
 var primaryDDRow = 4;              //Row number of the primary drop down


  var dropSS_      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS);
  var dropDData    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange).getValues();
  var activeCell   = dropSS_.getActiveCell();
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
  var activeRow    = activeCell.getRow();


  if(activeColumn==primaryDDCol && activeRow==primaryDDRow){ //added condition to restrict secondary to specific cell

    var dep_Col         = primaryDDCol;
    var dep_Row         = activeRow+1;
    var depCell         = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
    var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
    var validationRule  = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected)).build();

    depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);

  }

}


function getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected){

  var dependenList = [];
  var j = 0;
  if(dropDData != null){
    for(i=0; i<dropDData.length; i++){
      if(dropDData[i][0]==primarySelected){
        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];
        j++;

      }

    }

  }

  return dependenList;
}
```

[image]

This first dependent drop-down has the value for "Department" (B4) determining the value list for the drop-down at "Team" (B5).

For dependent drop-down 2 my script is as follows:

```
function dependent_drop_down_2(){
  var dataSS           = "Data Validation";             
  var primaryDataRange = "D2:D10";       
  var primaryDropRange = "A13:A20";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var dropSS = sheets[i].getName();
    if (dropSS != dataSS){
      // continue the rest of your code as before
      var primaryDropList  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange).getValues();     
      var primaryDropRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange);      
      var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList).build();      
      primaryDropRange.setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}


  //CREATE SECONDARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onEdit(){
 /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
 var dataSS       = "Data Validation";         //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
 var dropSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()         //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
 var allDataRange = "D2:E10";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent)
 var primaryDDCol = 1;               //Column number of the primary drop down
 var primaryDDRow = 13;           //Row number of the primary drop down


  var dropSS_      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS);
  var dropDData    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange).getValues();
  var activeCell   = dropSS_.getActiveCell();
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
  var activeRow    = activeCell.getRow();

  

  if(activeColumn==primaryDDCol && activeRow>=primaryDDRow){ //added condition to restrict secondary to specific rows and columns

    var dep_Col         = primaryDDCol+1;
    var dep_Row         = activeRow;
    var depCell         = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
    var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
    var validationRule  = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected)).build();

    depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);

  }

}

 

function getDependentList(dropDData,primarySelected){

  var dependenList = [];
  var j = 0;
  if(dropDData != null){
    for(i=0; i<dropDData.length; i++){
      if(dropDData[i][0]==primarySelected){
        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];
        j++;

      }

    }

  }

  return dependenList;

}
```

[image]

This second dependent drop-down has the value for "Equipment Category" (A13 to A20) determining the value list for the drop-down at "Equipment" (B13 to B20).

Sample Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExrcwfpJyQZYP7ZTE-uVB4nPmAwQpgYzB2XtjHO1rIw/edit#gid=0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SUGGESTION

Based on the information provided as well as the codes, you need to merge both into one consolidated script. That way, both drop-down functions will be run and checked at any given time (both on the `dependent_drop_down` and `onEdit` functions).

You can check this consolidated script below. Take note that I did not do any changes to it, I just combined both of the needed functions from each of your drop-down scripts into one.

```
function dependent_drop_down() {
  var dataSS = "Data Validation";
  var coverSS = "Cover";
  var primaryDataRange1 = "A2:A10";
  var primaryDropRange1 = "B4";
  var primaryDataRange2 = "D2:D10";
  var primaryDropRange2 = "A13:A20";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var dropSS = sheets[i].getName();
    if (dropSS != dataSS && dropSS != coverSS) {
      // continue the rest of your code as before

      // for the 1st dependent dropdown
      var primaryDropList1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange1).getValues();
      var primaryDropRange1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange1);
      var validationRule1 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList1).build();
      // for the 2nd dependent dropdown
      var primaryDropList2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(primaryDataRange2).getValues();
      var primaryDropRange2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS).getRange(primaryDropRange2);
      var validationRule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(primaryDropList2).build();

      // building both data validations    
      primaryDropRange1.setDataValidation(validationRule1);
      primaryDropRange2.setDataValidation(validationRule2);
    }
  }
}

// CREATE SECONDARY DROPDOWN LIST
function onEdit() {
  /* SET FOLLOWING VARIABLES */
  var dataSS = "Data Validation"; //Name of the sheet that contain data for dropdown lists
  var restrictList = ["Data Validation", "Cover"]; // array list of tabs that should not be updated
  // you can add or remove tab names on this list according to your preference
  var updateFlag = 1;
  var dropSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName()         //Name of the sheet which dropdown list to be created
  var allDataRange1 = "A2:B10";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent) for 1st dropdown
  var allDataRange2 = "D2:E10";       //Data range for dropdown list (both primary and dependent) for 2nd dropdown
  var primaryDDCol1 = 2;               //Column number of the primary drop down # 1
  var primaryDDRow1 = 4;
  var primaryDDCol2 = 1;               //Column number of the primary drop down # 2
  var primaryDDRow2 = 13;

  var dropSS_ = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dropSS);
  // getting values for dropdown # 1
  var dropDData1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange1).getValues();
  // getting values for dropdown # 2
  var dropDData2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(dataSS).getRange(allDataRange2).getValues();
  var activeCell = dropSS_.getActiveCell();
  var activeColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
  var activeRow = activeCell.getRow();
  var activeSheet = activeCell.getSheet();

  // loop that checks if the current active sheet is included in the array list of "restricted" sheets
  // if so, no value will be updated on that sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < restrictList.length; i++) {
    if (dropSS == restrictList[i]) {
      updateFlag--;
      break;
    }
  }

  // this part of the script will only work if the active sheet is not part of the "restricted" sheets array
  if (updateFlag) {
    // formula taken from your 1st dropdown, referencing values connected to the 1st dropdown
    if (activeColumn == primaryDDCol1 && activeRow == primaryDDRow1) {

      var dep_Col = primaryDDCol1;
      var dep_Row = activeRow + 1;
      var depCell = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
      var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData1, primarySelected)).build();

      depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);

    }
    // formula taken from your 2nd dropdown, referencing values connected to the 2nd dropdown
    else if (activeColumn == primaryDDCol2 && activeRow >= primaryDDRow2) {

      var dep_Col = primaryDDCol2 + 1;
      var dep_Row = activeRow;
      var depCell = dropSS_.getRange(dep_Row, dep_Col);
      var primarySelected = activeCell.getValue();
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(getDependentList(dropDData2, primarySelected)).build();

      depCell.setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}

function getDependentList(dropDData, primarySelected) {
  var dependenList = [];
  var j = 0;
  if (dropDData != null) {
    for (i = 0; i < dropDData.length; i++) {
      if (dropDData[i][0] == primarySelected) {
        dependenList[j] = dropDData[i][1];
        j++;
      }
    }
  }
  return dependenList;
}
```

Once the script is saved, you should be able to run both drop-downs at the same time.

### OUTPUT

[image]

### UPDATE

Based on the information you've provided on your latest comment, I've updated the script above wherein it now checks a defined array list of "restricted" tabs (i.e. tabs where you do not want the script to work) before running the `onEdit` function.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be more than happy to clarify them up for you.

Comment: Hi @mic test, this is exactly what I am looking for. One additional questions, in my real spreadsheet I have an additional tab (Cover) besides the "Data Validation" tab where I wouldn't want this script to run on (Added a mock version in the sample linked in the question for reference).  I tried adding a new var (coverSS) and `if (dropSS != dataSS && dropSS != coverSS)` but this doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to exclude tabs in the script so it runs on all other tabs but "Cover" and "Data Validation"?

Comment: Ah, I see. I've updated my answer regarding your latest comment; let me know if I was able to answer your query with it, or if there are additional clarifications needed.

Comment: Hi, just checking back in to see if we've covered all of your concerns with the updated code provided on the answer. If not, do let me know right away so that we can clarify it up.

Comment: Hi @Mic Test, thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Much appreciated for your guidance. I got lots to learn.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to know that this works perfectly for you.